# Spring MVC mapped method not being called using POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload a file using Spring MVC.
Here is the form in the .jsp page

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="file"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload your file please:
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    <form:errors path="file" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
</form:form>
```

In my controller I have the GET and POST methods:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getForm(Model model) {
    File fileModel = new File();
    model.addAttribute("file", fileModel);
    return "file";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String fileUploaded(Model model, @Validated File file, BindingResult result) {
    String returnVal = "successFile";
    logger.info("I am here!!!");
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        returnVal = "file";
    }else{
        MultipartFile multipartFile = file.getFile();
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

The validation is just to check if the file size is zero:

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    File imageFile = (File)target;
    logger.info("entered validator");
    if(imageFile.getFile().getSize()==0){
        errors.rejectValue("file", "valid.file");
    }
}
```

The method GET works fine and returns the file view, however the POST method in the controller does not get called. Nothing happens when the upload button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadInputFiles(@RequestParam("file1") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName,
        @RequestParam("fileType") String fileType){

    System.out.println("Upload File Controller has been called");
}
```

Form submission:

```
<form method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br /> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br /> <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, But it was a very silly error on my part. I had not included `<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>` in my jsp

Answer (score 0):

I think your configuration should be like below in mvc-servlet.xml file.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="500000" />
</bean>
```

and change your post api like below.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/uploadFile")
public String fileUploaded(Model model, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, BindingResult result) {
     String result = "not uploaded";
     if(!file.isEmpty()){
            MultipartFile multipartFile = file.getFile();
            //code for storing the file in server(in db or system)
      }
     else{
          result = "can not be empty;"
      }       
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your reply and I did change my post api, But it was a very silly error on my part. I had not included `<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>` in my jsp